# react-native redux Getting a bizzare Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) warning

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I'm Using redux-thunk

Im posting my customer details to database and then sending the response as a payload

this is my CustomerReducers

```
export default (state = intial_state ,actions) => {
    console.log('customer action',actions); //1
    switch(actions.type) { 

        case CUSTOMER_SAVE_SUCCESS:
        console.log('cus success',action.payload);  //2
        return {
        ...state,
            emailError:false ,
            contactError:false,          
            name:'', 
            email: '',
            address:'', 
            contact: '',                 
            loading:false
        };   

        default:    return state;
    }
}
```

the first console.log doesn't shows me this [image]

I only get the error when I try to access the **action.payload**

inside the second console.log statement.

Comment: you don't have a variable called `action` .. you mean `actions` ?

Comment: Thank you so much. It's an extremely careless mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling action.payload when it should be actions.payload.
Thanks to @azium for pointing it out